# Question involving improper integrals.

Tags: calculus, integration

Let us assume there's a positive and differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, also:
$\int_0^\infty f = L < \infty$ and $f'(x)$ is bounded. I'm required to prove:
$lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$.

Thanks a milliion!

Comment: Is $f'(x)$ bounded only from above or both sides?

Comment: @Belov: it is a positive function.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ bound the derivative, and suppose the limit of $f$ does not go to zero. Select $a > 0$  and define sequence $x_n$ going to infinity so that $f(x_n) > a$ and the triangles formed by the points $(x_n, f(x_n)), (x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{C}, 0)$, and $(x_n + \frac{f(x_n)}{C}, 0)$ do not overlap. The derivative bound guarantees that the graph of $f$ contains each of these triangles, and each has the same area, and so the function is not integrable.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose that $f'(x)\le M$. The [Mean Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) says that for some $\xi$ between $x$ and $a$
$$
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\right|=\left|f'(\xi)\right|\le M
$$
Then
$$
|f(a)|+M|x-a|\ge|f(x)|\ge|f(a)|-M|x-a|
$$
What is
$$
\int_{a-|f(a)|/M}^{a+|f(a)|/M}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints that motivate "why" this should be true. If the integral is finite and the function positive, that means that as you go further and further out (away from zero), the contribution to the integral should become smaller and smaller. Now suppose that the function itself did not go to zero in the limit. Then there must be a sequence of points (going off to infinity) where the function is positively bounded away from zero, say by $c \geq 0$. But since the area contribution needs to be getting smaller, at these points the function needs to reach $c$ quickly and descend again without adding lots of area. It is plain to see that in order for that area to shrink as the points get further out, it is necessary for the function to shoot up to $c$ faster and faster, and this will eventually violate any bound on the derivative.